# How to run custom missions in F-16 Multirole Fighter?

Tags: technical-issues, backwards-compatibility, f-16-multirole-fighter

I'm playing the old game by Novalogic called F-16 Multirole Fighter, but every time i select a mission I made from the mission editor which came with the game, I get an error which says file_loadfileex. Any one have any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-16_Multirole_Fighter) the game you speak of? I can create a tag for it if so.

Comment: Yes this indeed is the game